# In Drupal 7, How to prefix theme related tables in setting.php file

Tags: database

In Drupal commerce kickstart, I enabled "Commerce Kickstart Theme 7.x-2.4" theme for "Main site" and modified design as per the requirement. We are doing "Mobile site", and we took another theme "Omega 7.x-3.1" for different look and feel. Now, I need to connect the Main site database in settings.php file and tables related to only theme based which enabled in "Mobile Site". Can anybody give me the suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want to keep theme tables separate? What **are** theme tables, after all? I can't recall anything like that.

Comment: I changed the theme for responsive layout features of mobile site... but here I need to display content (i.e., all products information) related to main site. So I am asking any of these two ways of possiblity - In Mobile site, put theme as it is and prefix the node related tables or In Main site, put node related tables as it is and prefix the theme which was changed.